# Firebase Database: Search for Particular Item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building out an ordering tool.  Each order has an `id`, a unique identifier that I get from Firebase using the `push` method.  My question is: let's say I put a text field labeled "Order" in my page with a button next to it titled "Find".

What's the best way to retrieve (and maybe even structure) that data?  I am familiar with indexing on the Firebase database.  Basically, I want to enable searching for a particular order.  There could be thousands of them.  Is the below proper?

`var wantedOrder = firebase.database().ref('orders').equalTo("My Input Text");`

```
  "orders": {
    "abc123456": {
      "name": "My First Fake Order",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      },
    "abc123457": {
      "name": "My Second Fake Order",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

Firebase Rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      ".indexOn": ["name"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't directly use equalto.... You need to apply and orderBy*() method before that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an orderBy*() type of function before `equalTo()`, `startAt()` and `endAt()`.

In your particular case, I would use

```
var wantedOrder = firebase.database().ref('orders').orderByChild('name').equalTo('yourText').on(listener you want.....)
```

This will return the exact match of your search....

If you want to have a more flexible way, use `startAt()` and `endAt()`.

Comment: Sorry on a phone... Couldn't help the indentations

Comment: I didn't know if I needed to add a `$order` to the firebase rule...  I'll circle back if it don't work.  TY

Comment: Your rules are fine... The method you called was wrong... Look more into advanced querying in the firebase docs it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you two way to achieve what you are looking for.

1. (Not very efficient if you have huge data) You can get entire data through ValueEventListener of "Orders" node and then loop over every set of data for search keyword.
2. Have a look at this link they have similar dataset as yours.
   [Querying firebase through substring](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-search-a-Firebase-Realtime-Database-with-a-substring)